# JScrollPane "stretching" out the panel that I add to it

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I have to make a scrollable list where I can add a panel with 3 labels many times.
I kind of made it work but the first panels are stretched and occupy all the area of the JScrollPane and I can't figure out how to fix this, I tried changing layouts many times but still didn't manage to fix it.
I want the added panel to occupy a fixed size but I can't figure this out. Example in this picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNznP.png
The one on the left is the one that I get and the one on the right (edited) is how I want it to work.

This is my first day of Swing so the code is very likely a mess, sorry in advance.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JPanel viewportPanel;
    private JButton addButton,remButton;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private int counter = 0;
    private JLabel dateLabel,dateLabel_1,dateLabel_2;
    
    public MainWindow(boolean run) {
        //BUTTONS
        addButton = new JButton("Add");
        addButton.setLocation(521, 11);
        addButton.setSize(101, 100);
        addButton.addActionListener(this);
        
        remButton = new JButton("Remove");
        remButton.setLocation(521, 122);
        remButton.setSize(101, 100);
        remButton.addActionListener(this);
        
        //SCROLLPANE
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 501, 211);
        add(scrollPane);
        
        //PANELS
        viewportPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(viewportPanel);
        
        //FRAME
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 650, 273);
        setResizable(false);
        //setIconImage(new ImageIcon("epic.png").getImage());
        setLayout(null);
        if(run) setVisible(true);
        add(addButton);
        add(remButton);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == addButton) {
            //LABELS
            dateLabel = new JLabel("DATE");
            dateLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 28));
            dateLabel.setSize(500,500);

            dateLabel_1 = new JLabel("LABEL1");
            dateLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 22));
            dateLabel_1.setBounds(10, 45, 481, 30);
            
            dateLabel_2 = new JLabel("LABEL2");
            dateLabel_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.ITALIC, 22));
            dateLabel_2.setBounds(10, 45, 481, 30);
            
            //PANEL WITH ALL THE STUFF
            JPanel componentPanel = new JPanel();
            componentPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
            componentPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50,50));
            componentPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
            componentPanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
            componentPanel.add(dateLabel);
            componentPanel.add(dateLabel_1);
            componentPanel.add(dateLabel_2);
            
            viewportPanel.add(componentPanel);  //add panel with labels to viewportpanel
            counter++;
        }
        
        if(e.getSource() == remButton) {
            Component[] componentList = viewportPanel.getComponents();
            int lastElement = (componentList.length);
            viewportPanel.remove(--lastElement);
            --counter;
        }
        
        viewportPanel.revalidate();
        viewportPanel.repaint();
    }
}
```

Some help would be amazing!

Comment: `setLayout(null);` --  Learn the layout managers, and ***use*** the layout managers, and this will likely solve many of your layout problems.

Comment: Also, looks like you really want to use a JList or JTable

Comment: I'll look into JLists man, thanks.

Comment: @JoeMama42069 when you place a component into a container _**without**_ specifying the component's _preferred_ size, you are basically delegating the responsibility or adjusting the component's size to the container. In Java Swing, the `setSize()` methods are used to define the size of a component when layout manager is set to `null` . When a component uses a layout manager (including default), you must set the preferred size of the component using the corresponding method. In general, this is how it is done in Swing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, never do this:

```
setLayout(null);
```

Next, if you want things compressed at the top of a container, then use a layout that does this. such as a BorderLayout with the compressed items placed into a JPanel (perhaps one that uses a GridLayout) that is placed BorderLayout.PAGE_START

Actually, it looks as if your best solution is to us a JList, one that uses a custom renderer that places your time JLabel and two text JLabels into a JPanel and displays this in the list. So let's explore that.

First create a class to hold the data that is displayed by the JList, which looks to be a date and two lines of text:

```
public class ListItem {
    private LocalDate date;
    private String text1;
    private String text2;

    public ListItem(LocalDate date, String text1, String text2) {
        super();
        this.date = date;
        this.text1 = text1;
        this.text2 = text2;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getText1() {
        return text1;
    }

    public String getText2() {
        return text2;
    }   
}
```

Then let's create a renderer that a JList can use to display the above information in a JPanel. This is more complicated and requires that the class create a JPanel that places the labels where we want them, perhaps using a GridLayout with 1 column and 3 rows, plus some gaps between the rows: `setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 2 * gap, 2 * gap));`. The class must implement the `ListCellRenderer<T>` interface which has one method: `public Component getListCellRendererComponent(...)`. Java will pass in the paramters into this method, including a ListItem value, and we will use that value to fill in the JLabels that we add into this JPanel. Edited to highlight selected items.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ListItemRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer<ListItem> {
    private static final Color LIGHT_BLUE = new Color(204, 255, 255);
    private static final Color REDDISH_GREY = new Color(205, 126, 121);
    private DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
    private static final int GAP = 2;
    private Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP);
    private Border blackBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
    private Border redBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(REDDISH_GREY, 2);
    private JLabel dateLabel = new JLabel();
    private JLabel text1Label = new JLabel();
    private JLabel text2Label = new JLabel();
    
    public ListItemRenderer() {
        dateLabel.setFont(dateLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 14f));
        text1Label.setFont(text1Label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
        text2Label.setFont(text1Label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC));       
        
        int gap = 2;
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 2 * gap, 2 * gap));
        
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(emptyBorder, blackBorder));
        add(dateLabel);
        add(text1Label);
        add(text2Label);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends ListItem> list, ListItem value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (value != null) {
            String dateText = dateFormatter.format(value.getDate());
            dateLabel.setText(dateText);
            text1Label.setText(value.getText1());
            text2Label.setText(value.getText2());
        } else {
            dateLabel.setText("");
            text1Label.setText("");
            text2Label.setText("");
        }
        
        if (isSelected ) {
            setBackground(LIGHT_BLUE);
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(emptyBorder, redBorder));
        } else {
            setBackground(null);
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(emptyBorder, blackBorder));
        }
        return this;
    }
    
}
```

And now the main program that puts this all together, edited to show removing items:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    DefaultListModel<ListItem> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<ListItem> jList = new JList<>(listModel);
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList);
    private JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
    private JButton removeButton = new JButton("Remove");
    
    public MainPanel() {
        jList.setPrototypeCellValue(new ListItem(LocalDate.now(), 
                "This is text 1 for testing.  This is text 1 for testing.   This is text 1 for testing", 
                "This is text 2 for testing.  This is text 2 for testing.   This is text 2 for testing"));
        jList.setVisibleRowCount(4);
        jList.setCellRenderer(new ListItemRenderer());
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 3, 3));
        buttonPanel.add(addButton);
        buttonPanel.add(removeButton);
        
        addButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        removeButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        addButton.addActionListener(e -> addEvent());
        removeButton.addActionListener(e -> removeEvent());
        
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.add(buttonPanel);
        
        int gap = 5;
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap)); 
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane);
        add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }
    
    private void removeEvent() {
        int[] selectedIndices = jList.getSelectedIndices();
        for (int i = selectedIndices.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            listModel.remove(selectedIndices[i]);
        }
    }

    private void addEvent() {
        // this adds random stuff to the JList
        String text1 = "Some random text: " + randomText();
        String text2 = "Some random text: " + randomText();
            
        listModel.addElement(new ListItem(LocalDate.now(), text1, text2));
        
        // TODO: change this so that it adds *real* data to the JList
    }
    
    private String randomText() {
        Random random = new Random();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 + random.nextInt(3); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3 + random.nextInt(5); j++) {
                char c = (char) ('a' + random.nextInt('z' - 'a'));
                builder.append(c);
            }
            builder.append(" ");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new MainPanel());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

---

Output would look like:

[image]